# Can we do graph bfs and dfs without coloring?

Tags: graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I know how to do DFS and BFS with the graph node has some attribute like color, so that in the process of DFS or BFS, I can tell whether a node has been visited.
I am wondering if I am given a graph and the graph node has no color flag, how can I do DFS or BFS?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it's possible to do DFS without use of three colors , you can instead keep a boolean attribute in the class "Node" to see if it's been previously visited or not :

```
  void DFS-Visit(Node current , int time){
      current.visited = true;
      for (int i = 0 ; i < current.neighbor.length ; i++)
          if (!current.neighbor[i].visited)
              DFS-Visit(current.neighbor[i]);
      System.out.println(current.key);
      return;
  }
  void DFS(Node[] G){
       for (int i = 0 ; i < G.length; i++)
           G[i].visited = false;
       for (int i = 0 ; i < G.length; i++)
           if (!G[i].visited)
              DFS-Visit(G[i]);
       return;
  }
  class Node{
     Node[] neighbor;
     boolean visited;
     int key; // content of the node , it might be anything
  }
```